# Primefaces styles disappear after changing the url-pattern

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2.2 and primefaces 5.0
I want to get rid of the "faces" in the application link.
So i changed the web.xml and set the `url-pattern`:
from:

```
<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
```

to:

```
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

this does work and removes the ugly "faces" in the link, 
but i lost the primefaces css styles!

I'm using a wrong method to remove the "faces"?
or is there a way to make primefaces use it s styles again?

EDIT:
web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>report</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>report</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>report</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/report</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            300
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Could you post your whole *web.xml* instead?

Comment: Look in your browser's javascript console for any (404) errors related to loading resource file loading